# In ASP.NET MVC why might TempData not persist when Session does?

Tags: model-view-controller, tempdata

I have an ASP.NET MVC project which uses TempData to carry an object from one controller action to another - which is in fact the same action but a version that accepts HTTP posts.

On my development machine this works as expected. On the test machine the TempData value is null in the second controller action.

Forum posts which I've seen suggest checking that sessionState is working - which I have done. Both websites have sessionState set to InProc - neither web.config contains a sessionState entry but I've checked that Session.Mode is InProc. If I put an object in Session in the first controller action I can retrieve it in the second on both machines.

I can work around this by re-doing the process used to set TempData in the first controller action in the second but why might TempData be being lost on the test machine?

Comment: It is very important which version of ASP.NET MVC you are using. In ASP.NET MVC 1 TempData is persisted until the next request from the same browser, so you should only use TempData immediately before you redirect (immediately before returning a RedirectResult). Since ASP.NET MVC 2 the value will be removed from TempData after the request in which it is read (so it can live in multi-redirect scenario). So for more specific answer we need more details about your redirect scenario and ASP.NET MVC version your are using.

Comment: I inherited the project and it is using MVC 1. I'm not redirecting I'm using TempData to pass data between an action / view with a submit button and the action / view that accepts the postback. This works on one machine but not on another. As far as I can tell the relevant bits of web.config are the same on both machines.

Comment: If it's using ASP.NET MVC 1 you must be sure, that there is no other request from that client to your application between the GET and POST you have described. If there is any other request that will be identified as the same client, the TempData will be lost (doesn't mather if your application have read them or not) -I belive this link describes is pretty exact http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't reading it from say - a layout (master page) an extra time. To be sure, wrap the call where you set/get this values and write trace information out to make sure you are only calling it when you expect. I had a similar issue on an app a while back (mvc2) and it turned out I was reading it when it first seemed I wasn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however the development site and test site are running the same code. On the test site the TempData doesn't get to the master page.